# How can I create a table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made the table structure below. How can I add a second column of this table dynamically whenever I click `add1` link using javascript? The whole column from up to down.This same column must be repeated again and again

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="datble" class="form" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>                
            <td><a href="">Add1</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="">Add2</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td<a href="">Add3</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="">Add4</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Table strucutre did not get pasted

Comment: Are you missing an image, or did the edit take it away? Can't see any "table structure below".

Comment: A combination of `click` event and `append`

Comment: @afaolek there is the code now

Comment: `p` inside `tr` oh God Why?! :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

Comment: @tymeJV can you give me an example, i have tried changing the code for creating rows but all in vain

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Ok that can be removed but how about creating this column agian using javascript

Comment: @Huangism there is the table structure

Comment: @user3253289 Show us what you have tried so far. And still why on earth have you decided to put p-tags inside table rows? :)

Comment: Add a `column`? Did you mean `row`? There is no concept of a `column` in HTML? We have `tr` which is `table row` but no `tc`. By the way, you should edit the title to something like `How can I add a column (row?) to a table dynamically?`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a function to the link's click event. In that function, you need to iterate through each row, find the position where you want to add the column, and then insert it.

```
$(function(){
    // bind the function to the click event
    $("#add1").on("click", function(){
        // iterate through each row
        $("table tbody tr").each(function(){
            // insert the column HTML at the desired point
            $(this).children().first().after("<td>New Column</td>");
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NuB5h/)

If you want to make all of the links add the column when clicked, then just replace `#add1` with `.add` in the jQuery.

Comment: thanks it is doing the work,but i would like  it to append at the right side of the second column, forget the third column-that will come in later.And could you make it work such that if i click on link 3 none of the top cells in the column are displayed apart from starting with the one inline with this link 3

Comment: +2.5 for being close.how about displaying the new column at the end of the second ,leave out the thirdcolumn up to the last.and then making sure that the column above the link clicked is not shown but any below it are shown as you can see in the first table structure for row3 in case link3 is clicked,all the top cells are not shown.

Answer (score 1):

I created a JavaScript function that adds a row to your table.

I also removed the `<p>` tag because it's not valid HTML and makes no visual difference.

```
<table id="datble" class="form" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 1</a></td>
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 2</a></td>
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addColumn(element) {
        var tr = element.parentElement.parentElement;
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = '<label>Name</label>';
        td.innerHTML += '<input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />';
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
</script>
```

*EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood and thought you wanted to add a row. I changed the code to add a column instead.*

*EDIT 2: I changed the code so you can use it on multiple rows.*

Comment: +3 for understanding the requirement.but how about making it display all the columns below after clicking link 1 i.e it also shows the cell below with data of similar king to that cell opposite link 2.And for link 2 when clicked,to display the column as you have designed(ie minus the top one) it plus any below it

Comment: how about being able to work on the whole table.I have been trying out this code:function appendColumn(){var tbl=document.getElementById('my_table');
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
for(var i=0;i<tbl.rows.length;i++){
var newcell =tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length);
for(var j=0;j<colCount;j++){
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;}}
} but it doesn't do it.please leave the functionality of eliminating the column above that whose link has not been clicked in place.

Comment: you can also refer to mysecond  comment to Patrick Q for more clarity.